# cakePHP adding subfolders in Commands folder

Tags: php, cakephp, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to separate the Commands folder into sub folders for example:

```
├─ src/
│  ├─ Command/
│  │  ├─ FirstFolder/
│  │  │  ├─ FirstFolder_TestCommand.php
│  │  ├─ SecondFolder/
│  │  │  ├─ SecondFolder_TestCommand.php
```

I tried to debug the code and found that when we make the scanDir we are searching only inside Command and if we find something that it's not .php we will skip it.

Is there a way to separate in subfolders the commands or it's not introduce yet?

Forgot to mention I'm using cakePHP 3.8, but tried this on cakePHP 4.0 it was the same.

Sorry if this is already answer somewhere, I just never found it.

Answer (score 1):

For now it cannot be done without creating a separated plugin for each subfolder you need to add in commands.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a late response but it can be done by overiding the CommandRunner and specifying your own command list in addition to the existing one:

Example:

1. Create **CustomCommandrunner.php** that extends CommandRunner And copy the run() function from the commandRunner
2. add a static list that will hold your custom commands **$specialCommandList**
3. add your custom commands manually by calling addMany method **$commands->addMany(self::$specialCommandList);**

> CustomCommandRunner.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Command;

use Cake\Console\CommandRunner;
use Cake\Command\VersionCommand;
use Cake\Console\Command\HelpCommand;
use Cake\Console\CommandCollection;
use Cake\Console\CommandInterface;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;
use Cake\Console\Exception\MissingOptionException;
use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Core\PluginApplicationInterface;
use RuntimeException;

class CustomCommandRunner extends CommandRunner
{
    ---->public static array $specialCommandList = [];

    public function run(array $argv, ?ConsoleIo $io = null): int
    {
        $this->bootstrap();

        $commands = new CommandCollection([
            'help' => HelpCommand::class,
        ]);
        if (class_exists(VersionCommand::class)) {
            $commands->add('version', VersionCommand::class);
        }
        $commands = $this->app->console($commands);

        add this line ----->$commands->addMany(self::$specialCommandList); 

        if ($this->app instanceof PluginApplicationInterface) {
            $commands = $this->app->pluginConsole($commands);
        }
        $this->dispatchEvent('Console.buildCommands', ['commands' => $commands]);
        $this->loadRoutes();

        if (empty($argv)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Cannot run any commands. No arguments received.');
        }
        // Remove the root executable segment
        array_shift($argv);

        $io = $io ?: new ConsoleIo();

        try {
            [$name, $argv] = $this->longestCommandName($commands, $argv);
            $name = $this->resolveName($commands, $io, $name);
        } catch (MissingOptionException $e) {
            $io->error($e->getFullMessage());

            return CommandInterface::CODE_ERROR;
        }

        $result = CommandInterface::CODE_ERROR;
        $shell = $this->getCommand($io, $commands, $name);
        if ($shell instanceof Shell) {
            $result = $this->runShell($shell, $argv);
        }
        if ($shell instanceof CommandInterface) {
            $result = $this->runCommand($shell, $argv, $io);
        }

        if ($result === null || $result === true) {
            return CommandInterface::CODE_SUCCESS;
        }
        if (is_int($result) && $result >= 0 && $result <= 255) {
            return $result;
        }

        return CommandInterface::CODE_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Finally under /bin/cake/cake.php file modify it so it will use your custom runner

> cake.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
// Check platform requirements
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/requirements.php';
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Application;
use App\Console\Command\CustomCommandRunner;

// use Cake\Console\CommandRunner;

// Build the runner with an application and root executable name.
// $runner = new CommandRunner(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'), 'cake');


CustomCommandRunner::$specialCommandList = [
    'DisplayUsers' => 'App\Command\subfolder\DisplayUsersCommand',
];

$runner = new CustomCommandRunner(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'), 'cake');


exit($runner->run($argv));
```

Of course this is not the official solution and comes with some disadvantages:

- Needs manual update of your subfolder commands
- in case the plugin gets updated you will need to revise the code and update the run function in your custom runner to keep it updated.
- not sure how it will behave in case of commands with same name